# Modify HashMap with values from other HashMap whose keys are borrowed from the first one

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Suppose I have two `HashMap`s, `m1` and `m2` with the same set of non-`Copy` keys, except `m2`’s keys are borrowed from `m1` (say, `m1` has `String` keys and `m2` has `&str` keys borrowed from `m1`). Is it possible to iterate through `m1` and update its values using the corresponding values from `m2`? The compiler believes that since `m2` borrows (immutably) from `m1`, borrowing `m1` mutably (say, through `iter_mut()` or `get_mut()`) should not be allowed.

Here is an MVE, demonstrating two attempts at iteration:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut m1 = HashMap::<_, _>::from_iter([("a".to_owned(), 1), ("b".to_owned(), 2)]);
    let m2 = m1
        .iter()
        .map(|(k, v)| (k.as_str(), v))
        .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>();

    for (k, v) in m1.iter_mut() {
        *v += m2[k.as_str()];
    }

    for (&k, &v) in m2.iter() {
        *m1.get_mut(k).unwrap() += v;
    }
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `m1` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:10:16
   |
5  |     let m2 = m1
   |              -- immutable borrow occurs here
...
10 |     for (k, v) in m1.iter_mut() {
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
11 |         *v += m2[k.as_str()];
   |               -- immutable borrow later used here

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `m1` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:15:4
   |
5  |     let m2 = m1
   |              -- immutable borrow occurs here
...
14 |     for (&k, &v) in m2.iter() {
   |                     --------- immutable borrow later used here
15 |         *m1.get_mut(k).unwrap() += v;
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
```

I believe that what I'm trying to do is sound because modifying existing values of a `HashMap` won't cause any of its keys to move, and so `m2`’s references to `m1`’s keys will remain valid. But it doesn't seem possible to express this to the compiler?

I've considered using `Rc<String>` keys or just `usize` and storing the `String`s in a `Vec`, but I'm wondering if there's not a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, no, the compiler cannot allow you `&mut` access to `m1` because you could e.g. invoke `.clear()` and destroy the values that are being borrowed by `m2`.

Using `Rc` for the keys seems like a sensible solution to me.

Another option to consider would be using an interior mutability type (`Cell` or `RefCell`) for `m1`'s values, which would allow you to mutate them without `&mut` access to `m1`. Since the values are numbers, `Cell` is probably a good fit since it has no reference-counting overhead like `RefCell` does.